# Differentiate between indexOf 1 and 11

Tags: jquery

Can some one please tell what should I do to get this:

`"1,2,11".indexOf("1") != -1`  as true, but

`"0,2,11".indexOf("1") != -1`  as false

I want 11 to be taken fully.

Comment: You can't. Not with your ordinary indexOf. Use regular expressions instead.

Comment: @A.Rama Can you please suggest one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) on strings will never get what you ask. Since it searches for the occurrence of texts and `"1"` occurrs on `"11"`, it will always "find it".

If your string follows that pattern, call [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on the string and then use [`Array's .indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) on the resulting array should to get what you expect:

```
"1,2,11".split(",").indexOf("1") != -1 // true
"0,2,11".split(",").indexOf("1") != -1 // false
```

Comment: I'm embarrassed that I never thought of [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)...